# Duration of a transit visa in Abu Dhabi

Tags: transit-visas, uae, abu-dhabi, auh, azerbaijani-citizens

I hold an Azerbaijani passaport. I have a flight from Baku to Abu Dhabi arriving at 13:05 on 12 June. My onward flight from Abu Dhabi to Belgrade leaves about 50 hours later, on 14 June at 13:45. Is it okay if I get a 48 hour transit visa or do I have to get one for 96 hours? My flight from Baku to Abu Dhabi is a round-trip ticket, from 12 June to 19 June. My return ticket from Belgrade to Abu Dhabi is on 18 June. Which visa I should apply for?

Comment: I suggest you also ask this question in "Gəzəyənlər" FB group. I found a [related question](https://www.facebook.com/groups/238282336566990/?multi_permalinks=1754729068255635) there. This group has many Azeri members who are frequently traveling to UAE. Then you can also post the response here, if you get one.

Answer (score 2):

From the UAE [Government Portal](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visit-visas/transit-visa#:%7E:text=The%20UAE%20issues%20two%20types,transit%20visas%20are%20not%20extendable.),

> The validity of the visa is 48 hours from entry into the UAE, and you must leave the UAE within 48 hours from arrival.

Your stay in the UAE is 48 hours 45 minutes. To be on the safe side, get the 96 hour transit visa for your outbound flight for 50 AED and get the free 48 hour transit visa for your return flight.

So, in total, you'll need 2 transit visas.